# regular expression xpath to remove a specific node from a body xml

Tags: xml, xpath, filter, nsregularexpression, wso2-esb

given this body xml:

```
<NUM>
<VAL>
<TRANS> 2 </TRANS>
<TRANS> 3 </TRANS>
<TRANS> 4 </TRANS>
<TRANS> MG </TRANS>
<ATTACH> PROVA </ATTACH>
</VAL>
</NUM>
```

I would like as a result:

```
<NUM>
<VAL>
<TRANS> 2 </TRANS>
<TRANS> 3 </TRANS>
<TRANS> 4 </TRANS>
<ATTACH> PROVA </ATTACH>
</VAL>
</NUM>
```

In practice I would like to select all the xml but remove only the last node named trans.

Comment: The task is most suited  for XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

One XSLT approach to remove the `<TRANS> MG </TRANS>` element that satisfies your request may be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">         
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="NUM/VAL/TRANS[last()]" />
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NUM>
  <VAL>
    <TRANS> 2 </TRANS>
    <TRANS> 3 </TRANS>
    <TRANS> 4 </TRANS>
    <ATTACH> PROVA </ATTACH>
  </VAL>
</NUM>
```

Please notice that it removes the `last()` occurrence of the `<TRANS>` element in the sequence, and not the last element before the `<ATTACH>` element.

Comment: the body remains the same, hasn't eliminated anything, why?  @zx485